# plsql cannot use variables in sql select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am getting very fed up of APEX in recent days, i am trying to run a interactive report within application express and cannot seem to use variables i declare within my sql queries. Below is the error, i also included the code that works. the get_longlat() function is tested and works it returns a SDO_GEOMETRY data type.

> ORA-06550: line 7, column 12: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to '||' ORA-06550: line 7, column 1: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored

```
DECLARE
l_query VARCHAR2(4096);
l_location SDO_GEOMETRY := get_longlat(v('P2_POSTCODE'));
BEGIN

l_query := '
                SELECT
                "VENUE_ID",
                "VENUE_NAME",
                "CITY",
                "VENUE_NO",
                "POSTCODE",
                dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                "DESCRIPTION",
                SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION, '  || l_location || ',0.005,''unit=mile'') "G_LOCATION"                
                FROM   "GAMEVENUE"
                WHERE (SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION,' || l_location || ',''distance=250 unit=mile'') = ''TRUE'');';

RETURN l_query;
```

This works

```
l_query := '
                SELECT
                "VENUE_ID",
                "VENUE_NAME",
                "CITY",
                "VENUE_NO",
                "POSTCODE",
                dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                "DESCRIPTION",
                SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION, MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE(-4.1530439,50.371089,NULL),NULL,NULL),0.005,''unit=mile'') "G_LOCATION"                
                FROM   "GAMEVENUE"
                WHERE (SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION,SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE(-4.1530439,50.371089,null),null,null),''distance=250 unit=mile'') = ''TRUE'')';
```

Comment: || only works with character types, or types that can be implicitly converted to character types.  The || operator concatenates character strings and CLOB data.

Answer (score 1):

Because `SDO_GEOMETRY` is not of type `char` or `number`( implicitly considerable as char ), you can't use it in direct concetenation.
Try this instead :

```
l_query := '
                SELECT
                "VENUE_ID",
                "VENUE_NAME",
                "CITY",
                "VENUE_NO",
                "POSTCODE",
                dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                "DESCRIPTION",
                SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION, MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY('||l_sdo_gtype||','||l_sdo_srid||',MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE('||l_longitude||','||l_latitude||',NULL),NULL,NULL),0.005,''unit=mile'') "G_LOCATION"                
                FROM   "GAMEVENUE"
                WHERE (SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(G_LOCATION,SDO_GEOMETRY('||l_sdo_gtype||','||l_sdo_srid||',SDO_POINT_TYPE('||l_longitude||','||l_latitude||',null),null,null),''distance=250 unit=mile'') = ''TRUE'')';
```

where `l_sdo_gtype`,`l_sdo_srid`, `l_longitude`, `l_latitude` are of type number;

Comment: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-06550: line 10, column 78: ORA-00936: missing expression". If you believe your query is syntactically correct, check the "Use Generic Column Names" checkbox below to proceed without parsing.